# WebStorm: no autocomplete for React

Tags: webstorm

On WebStorm website they have screenshot for React autocomplete:

[image]

However, it doesn't work on my WebStorm:

[image]

I have switched my JavaScript language version to React JSX in `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript`.

In the file, I right click then selected `react-DefinitelyTyped` and `react-dom-DefinitelyTyped` from User JavaScript Library, and it is still not working, neither.

Any advice?

Comment: Try typing `<DiceBut`

Comment: It works!!!!, thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try typing

```
<Dice
```

instead of

```
Dice
```

The auto-complete is looking for the start of a tag.